# Поиск репозиториев GitHub на RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Программа должна искать репозитории на GitHub по термину, введенному в текстовое поле,  и выводит найденные репозитории списком. Получаю ошибку в определении `sequence2$`:

> Error: Type Observable is not assignable to
>   type Observable

и  при подписывании на событие `sequence2$.subscribe()`:

> Error: Argument of type 'string | ResponseModel' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ResponseModel'
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ResponseModel'

Подскажите, как правильно расставить типы.

```js
import { from, fromEvent, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, catchError, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface ResponseModel {
  count: number;
  items: Repositories[];
};

interface Repositories {
  urlRepo: string;
  title: string;
  lang: string;
};

const searchField: HTMLInputElement  = document.querySelector('.search-field') as HTMLInputElement;
const repositories: HTMLUListElement = document.querySelector('.repositories') as HTMLUListElement;
const urlGithub: string = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories';
const errorText: string = 'No found =(';

const sequence$ = fromEvent(searchField, 'input');

const clearResult = ():void => {
  if (repositories) {
    repositories.innerHTML = '';
  }
};

const sequence2$: Observable<string | ResponseModel> = sequence$
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(clearResult),
    switchMap((event: KeyboardEvent) => request(event)
      .pipe(catchError(error => of('Error: ${errorText}')))
    )
  );

sequence2$.subscribe(result => showRepo(result));

function request(event: KeyboardEvent): Observable<Repositories> {
  const url: string = `${urlGithub}?q=${(event.target as  HTMLInputElement).value}`;
    return from(fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
};

function showRepo(res: ResponseModel) {
  if (!res.items || !res.items.length) {
    const error =  document.createElement('span');
    error.innerText = errorText;
    repositories.appendChild(error);
    return;
  }
  for (let i=0; i<res.items.length; i++) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = res.items[i].urlRepo;

    const language = document.createElement('span');
    language.innerText = res.items[i].lang;
    if(repositories) {
      const listRepo = document.createElement('li');
      listRepo.className = "repositories__list";
      listRepo.appendChild(link);
      listRepo.appendChild(language);
      repositories.appendChild(listRepo);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<ul class="repositories"></ul>
```

Comment: создайте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и нормально отформатируйте код, покажите где возникает ошибка, вопрос ведь неполный :(

Comment: ну так у вас поток генерирует событие с типом `string | ResponseModel`, а `showRepo` принимает параметром переменную типа `ResponseModel`, ошибка риторическая. Да и к тому же функция `request` возвращает поток, который сгенерирует событие с типом `Repositories`, у вас просто путаница с типами

Comment: @overthesanity, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить типы